# Admob - can't create any ads (admob wizard crappy?)

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm trying to create some ads in Admob, but on last step I always get error:

```
There were problems with your submission
```

but it didn't specify WHERE. I swear god, there are no errors on whole page, all fields are correctly filled, I see no red shapes around fields, everything match criterias written under fields,  but I stil get this error - without any explanation. Has anybody same experiences? It's totally frustrating :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it was google's fault - after 3 hours of trying I just let it go, and on the evening of same day I tried just save it again (with no changes) - and it suddently worked. I wrote to google about this mystery, but (again) without success.

However I must (again!) strongly criticize google, their admob wizard is crappy, this was not the first problem I had. Next few days I had many many problems with my ads - they approved my ad, and when I copied it (without changes) it was dissaproved. After 2-3 times save it was approved. Like random behaviour, or I don't know what is it.

**Conclusion: I can't understand how such big company can have such LAME LAME LAME errors on their sites, in admob, in android sdk, in their docs, in their support teams (which mostly don't answer) etc...Google, wake up!!!**

Comment: I filed a support issue with AdMob support regarding this exact issue (admob-publisher-support@google.com).   Support rep said they were "escalated this issue to our technical team on priority".  That was two days ago.  I've heard nothing since.  I will update here if anything happens.  I'm not optimistic, considering this thread started 6 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while using lates Google Chrome... Then I tried FireFox and everything worked fine.
Very strange ;-)

Comment: also tried FF (latest) and IE, but same problem as in Chrome...I can't understand this

Comment: yeah same problem. Firefox not resolving it