# AdMob - "Invalid or non-existent app url" while creating an ad

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am trying to create a house-ad campaign for my Android application, but unfortunately encountered a problem while providing an URL.

Please find error message below:

```
There were problems with your submission.
Invalid or non-existent app url
```

What is strange... when I provide an address for any website (not linking to Google Play application), followed by `http://`, there is no problem at all!

Has anyone of you also encounter such a bug on AdMob website?

For your information, I have checked this behavior on Google Chrome, IE7 and Firefox - no change.

This may be possibly a duplicate of:
[Admob - can't create any ads (admob wizard crappy?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642180/admob-cant-create-any-ads-admob-wizard-crappy)

... but I have decided to find a solution in new thread.

Best regards,
Bartosz Ostrowski.

Comment: What link did you use?

Comment: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name> and market://details?id=<package_name>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be solved. I have received an e-mail from AdMob Publisher Support saying that the problem will be solved by the end of the week - it is solved the same day.

Now "market://..." link is accepted without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this link from the android developer page in the format:

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

(do not include the < or >)

If that doesn't work or gives any errors then try:

`market://details?id=package_name`

source is here: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

EDIT: I just added one today (June 7, 2013) and no issues, used
`market://details?id=com...`

Comment: Did you try the "market" one too? If so, try waiting until tomorrow, as I've encountered some strange things on AdMob that usually resolve themselves by trying later...I know probably not what you want to hear/read

Comment: Are you actually writing "http://" "http://play.google..." or just "play.google.."? Couldn't get that to format right...

Comment: I am in the same boat. Weird behaviour. Everything was working before.Thought _ in a link might be a problem. But nope. tried all combos. Not sure what is happening.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I guess there must be an issue with Admob today?

Comment: i have the same problem he had 3 days ago, but now.. anyone has any info?

Comment: @DomeWTF still the same for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix. It is a crappy workaround, but if you use the web link you can get your ad working.

Use the https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id= url.

Then use http://goo.gl/ to create an short url. If you use this short url your url will be approved.

Only disadvantage is clicking the ad first opens the browser and then the Play store. I also posted this problem on the Google Admob Group so I hope there will be a fix soon. In the meanwhile the above solution will help showing houseads despite this issue.